# SSIS: Remove all rows from outputbuffer

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, xml-validation, output-buffering

In my attempts to process a particularly large xml file, I am using the `XmlReader` to loop through the xml and LINQ to Xml to create `XElements` for each chunk of the xml within the document.

On successfully parsing the data and validating it against it's schema, I write the data to a set of SSIS output buffers. If a schema error is found, I want to clear the data in output buffers for the file and abort processing.

I am using `Outputbuffer.AddRow()` to add rows to my output buffers but I cannot see a method to remove rows which I have added to my buffers. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method to delete outputbuffer row, store rows in a `datatable` or `list(of )` , do the validation before adding , if it is true add a rows from list or datatable to the outputbuffer.

**Or** You can add a boolean column to the output buffer, if schema error found, set this column to True, and filter rows using a conditional split.

```
[boolColumn] == False
```